# Site Template Urls

Tags: site-template, content-editor-web-part, url, url-rewriting

I have a SharePoint site, and saved it as a Template.

My problem is, I have a third part WebPart that references in his settings, the URL of the site.

When I create a new site using the template, that webpart is referecing the wrong URL (the URL of the template site).

There is a way to get the url of the new site?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 2010, then you can import that template into Visual Studio.  At that point there is a lot of cleanup work to produce a valid WebTemplate package, but you can include code that can put web parts on a page or change web part properties as needed through feature receivers that fire on activation.

Answer (score 0):

Check your third party WebPart properties, maybe you can put a **relative** url, if it's possible you won't have a problem using exported template.